# Why is org.eclipse.uml2.uml.Class not a subclass of ECores EClass?

Tags: uml, ecore

I am trying to understand the relationships between the UML implementation in ECore and its classes.

In the UML abstract syntax there are classes such as `Class`, `Property`, `Operation`, etc. and they all extend (through a rather long hierarchy) from EObject. But why not from EClass instead, wouldn't that be more intuitive?

Answer (score 0):

UML metaclasses Class, Property, Operation, etc. extend EObject and not Eclass because they are EObject and not EClass ...
I mean that EClass, EOperation, etc. are the EMF core used to implement metamodels as UML for example so UML metaclasses are instances of EClass => EObject.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't completely understand it. Could you give some more details and maybe an example of a metaclass that extends from `EClass`. I know `EClass` extends `EObject`, same as UMLs `Class` but still `Class` does not extend from `EClass`.

Comment: It is related about how EMF works please take a look at http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/emf-tutorial/ 
UML metamodel have been done thanks to EMF i.e. creating instances of EClass (UML Class, UML Property, etc.). Then a code generation have been performed to generate the UML implementation from this UML metamodel description. All generated classes Class, Property, etc. implements EObject to have a basic set of service for example serialization.